# How do I ColorQuantize to a predetermined mosiac builder's pallet of limited choices?

Tags: image-processing, color

If one is already working with a specific pallet of colors (say 9 colors of jelly bean in a mosaic) is there a good way to convert any image into those predetermined color choices? The `ColorQuantize` function makes its own color selections that when translated and "printed" in the predetermined pallet result in seeming poor art choices with both low contrast and erratic emphasis.

Answer (score 13):

Color quantization works by reducing the number of colors on the basis of colors that already appear in the image. With the reduced set of colors, all pixels in the image are converted to the best possible choice.

The *best possible choice* is usually a color from the reduced set that is closest to the pixel in the image. Therefore, you need a distance measure between two colors to calculate which color is the best match.

That being said, no one stops you from defining colors yourself and writing a function that gives for each input color the best matching color from the set of manually chosen colors. Let me give an example where I take 32 colors from one of the `ColorData` indexed color schemes:

```
With[{cols = List @@@ (ColorData[24] /@ Range[32])},
 selectColor[rgb : {_, _, _}] := First[SortBy[cols, Norm[rgb - #] &]]
];

img = Import[
  "http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/canoe_water_nature_221611.jpg"]
ImageApply[selectColor, img]
```

An alternative for `selectColor` function using `Nearest`.

```
With[{cols = List @@@ (ColorData[24] /@ Range[32])}, 
      selectColor[rgb : {_, _, _}] := Flatten@Nearest[cols, rgb, 1]];
```

This uses an image like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

to create

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Obviously, this set of colors are missing green tones, so let's try a better set:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you use this with

```
With[{cols = 
   List @@@ 
    Flatten[Table[
      ColorConvert[Hue[v, 1, b], "RGB"], {v, 0, 1, .1}, {b, .1, 
       1, .3}]]},
 selectColor[rgb : {_, _, _}] := First[SortBy[cols, Norm[rgb - #] &]]
 ]
```

you will get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That should give you a start. For faster processing, you should compile this function and apply it in parallel on the pixel matrix.

### Edit: Compiled version

```
With[{cols = 
   List @@@ 
    Flatten[Table[
      ColorConvert[Hue[v, s, b], "RGB"], {v, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 
       1, .3}, {b, 0, 1, .3}]]},
 fC = Compile[{{rgb, _Real, 1}}, 
   Module[{min = 100.0, currMin = 100.0, minCol = cols[[1]]},
    Do[
     If[(currMin = Norm[rgb - c]) < min,
      minCol = c;
      min = currMin
      ]
     , {c, cols}];
    minCol
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
   ]
 ]
```

And then

```
Image[fC@ImageData[img]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or if you like to make it more autumn-like, give only a small color range

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is pretty cool. I think `Nearest` can be used in the `selectColor` function like this `Flatten@Nearest[cols, rgb, 1]`. The results look similar.

Comment: @AnjanKumar Yes, in high-level code `Nearest` is the better alternative. I was giving the `Norm` approach as I had compilability in mind. Feel free to edit my answer if you like to have `Nearest` included in the answer.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: That's amazing!  Thanks

Comment: Halirutan:   Something I didn't understand before running your code was just how much artistic emphasis can be achieved with the right pallet inputs.I was working from a photo children on playground and stock color quantize that yielded many shades of wood chip.   Pallet choices that focused on the children and not the wood chips gave sensible results.

Comment: There is buil-it `ColorDistance` (starting from version 10) which should give better results than `Nearest` in RGB colorspace.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I know. Additionally, RGB is not a good choice for calculating metric color distances. What I tried is to present the general approach. I hope that the OP investigates on his own and reads some introduction about color spaces and perception, if she/he is really interested in the matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ColorQuantize in this application by specifying the desired color palette using Colorize and ColorRules. This code uses a color palette cols (borrowed from halirutan's answer) and applies it to the canoe picture (also borrowed from halirutan):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG7J1.png"]; 
cols = Flatten[Table[ColorConvert[Hue[v,1,b],"RGB"],{v,0,1,0.2}, {b,0.1,1,.3}]];
Colorize[ClusteringComponents[ColorQuantize[img, Length[cols]]],
           ColorRules -> Thread[Range[Length[cols]] -> cols]]
```

[image]

I suppose a less garish color choice might be appropriate... You should keep two things in mind: First, the original colors from `ColorQuantize` and the chosen colors `cols` share no similarity, which looks artistic but is different from halirutan's approach, who tries to find *nearest colors*. As a consequence, you might want to consider turning `Dithering->False` in `ColorQuantize` as this tries to simulate more color shades by sprinkling neighbouring colors. This doesn't really make sense with random colors. Here is the output without dithering

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As I understand, effectively you just replace the colors selected by `ColorQuantize` with your own without taking into account color distances. That's explain why the result is so bad. Probably considering color distances would improve it.

Comment: I made an edit to your post, mainly because I thought it's good to point out what dithering does. Alexey has a valid point, although I think someone reading through both of our answers will realize that a replacement of colors does not preserve the feel of the original image. +1

Comment: For the record, ColorQuantize is much faster on the computer while the Nearest / Norm approach seems like stronger choice for jelly bean mosaic art - - if only for the speed at which the more evenly outlined solid color areas can be assembled.   : )

Answer (score 1):

In Mathetica 11.3 `ColorQuantize` can take an image and a list of colors to do exactly what you ask for:

[image: ColorQuantize in 11.3 with predefined palette]